# Android Volley select requested data

Tags: android, android-volley

Does anyone know any tutorials on android Volley to select specific data from the database? because the tutorials i found already had the data ready in their URL. what i want is to pass a userID to retrieve username, email, password and etc. from my database via a String or JSON Object request to be displayed in my profile screen's textviews.

Comment: you can use StringRequest and Override getParams() method to get the data from database

Comment: Tutorial Link: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial/

Comment: Let us know here if it helps you!!

Comment: sure, i'll try it out. thanks